# How to get image coordinates and color data per pixel clicking on a displayed image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, coordinates, interactive

I loaded several PNG files into Matlab and displayed them with no problem but was wondering if there is a way to point (or click) on a pixel and immediately get its pixel coordinates and color (RGB), in real time, either as an output on-screen or stored in some variable.

For example, I have a 64 x 64 face photo to serve as a ground truth image for an eye detection algorithm.  The algorithm will return the bounding box for an eye, but, to check it, I want to manually extract coordinates by clicking or mousing around the image as it is plotted, and also color information about the pixels on which I click or mouse.

Please feel free to suggest another language, software, or environment if Matlab does not support such interactivity.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As a By the way, I have been making very complex UI intensive GUI's for the past year and a half in MATLAB and haven't found one thing I can't do with enough creativity. MATLAB will pretty much support all the interactivity you could want :)

Comment: Matlab is amazing!  Out of curiosity, are the GUIs you make usable outside Matlab?  I know I have to make them in Matlab, but after one is made, can I say, give the executable or UI file to someone without Matlab?

Comment: If you have the MATLAB compiler, you can create a windows standalone executable which will allow anyone to run your GUI without MATLAB installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Data Cursor does **exactly** what you want:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html

It is the icon to the right of the "rotate" icon in the image toolbar.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  Thank you for the perfect answer!  The bottom of the linked page also details an Export function, which helps bring the data into a program!  (Now I just need to find a way to automate this process: click, append new row to matrix...)  But between data points and the export command, I think there is enough flexibility here to pretty much load images and analyze their pixel data nimbly.

Comment: This is undocumented, but you can actually override the data cursor, and what you would do is modify the "buttondownfcn" of your axes, and on the click, you would automatically create the data cursor, but then you can add the data to your matrix and have full access to your variables. See my new answer which might be more helpful for your application

Comment: You can also override the update function - matlab gives instructions on how to do this in the help file for datacursormode. For example, I use this to find and display column numbers in multi-line graphs. You can get access to the data matrices by getting the x-data, y-data, z-data, c-data, etc of the "target".

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, there is a built in tool called impixel, which will allow you to click on an image and get pixel values and location automatically. There is no data cursor that pops up, but what the data cursor is returning, impixel is also, and you could easily display this with a uicontrol (text).